# Xcode cannot sign in with Apple ID

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, apple-id

Recently I wanted to archive my App with Xcode, then Xcode said that I must input my Apple ID and password again. Perhaps my login information was lost. I tried again, but it always failed.

If I input a wrong password, I get a correct response:
[image]

It said my Apple ID or password is incorrect. That can prove my network environment is okay.

However, if input the right credentials, it would respond nothing but only show busy:

[image]

I have tried a VPN to solve this problem but nothing works. Who can help me?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can sign in using the same password on developer.apple.com?

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes, I just login itunesconnect with this ID and password.

Comment: I think itunesconnect and developer.apple.com don't use the same login system, so be sure check with developer.apple.com too.

Comment: @ThomasW No problem, I confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably find the answer.

[Hangs when trying to sign in using Apple ID](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24154)

My macbook is secondhand, I don't know why it doesn't have a serial number. When login with Apple Id under El Capital(Mac OS X 10.11), the system tries to check the serial number then my mac hangs.
[image]

That's not only the Xcode problem but also AppStore and other places need to login with Apple Id in the system.

I have two options to solve this problem. one is recover the system to 10.10, another is go to apple store to fix it.

Comment: I have downgraded my system to 10.10(Yosemite), it works perfectly now.