# how to add the apple id in Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I am facing problem in adding the new apple id in xcode 7.3, it shows waiting since long although i have entered authentic credential and also checked proper internet connection.

[image]

Comment: Quit Xcode and reopen it then try.

Comment: I have tried reopen xcode also the osx(el capitan). but still not working.

Comment: Please go through the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929561/xcode-cannot-sign-in-with-apple-id

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani have you found the solution? I am also facing same issue from long time, still bad luck, please help.

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Yes we found solution and I am giving my in my Question wait a miunut.

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae look up the answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically after a long time:

I am getting the problem why it comes:

**In my case, Mac mini doesn't have the serial num it display unavailable so the problem comes.**

**Just like that**

[image]

**Basically, it comes when Apple unable to verify your mac for some reason so you have to contact to apple care.**

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae I think that's only the reason that Apple is not verified your Mac.

Comment: so what should i do now any suggestion pls

Comment: I got update from app store, i updated the software, now i am able to login with my apple id.

Comment: In your case what did you do about serial number.

Comment: So, I contact apple care and they resolved my problem

Comment: Basically, it comes apple unable to verify you mac for some reason so you have to contact to apple care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149075/discussion-between-minnukaanae-and-salman-ghumsani).

Comment: VMware I think that is the problem  it comes apple unable to verify.

Comment: Yes Plz tell me

Comment: Without having apple paid account can i run app directly in ios device from xcode

Comment: I think it is not possible because of the .ipa file bind with certificate and provisioning for validation to run in the device.

Comment: i don't have paid account so i cannot run on real device/i cannot get .ipa file? but i found this https://stackoverflow.com/q/38301229/5594218,

Comment: The main problem is xcode not recognizing my device.

Comment: First one if possible then let me know when you successfully run the application without apple paid account.
The second one it seems like there is a problem with the device so reconnect your device also check your deployment target and mobile phone capability or check the developer disk image.

Comment: I am new to ios, i completed login screen with web service long back ago and used simulator to test. Now i want to test it on real device,  I am using xcode 8.1 and device version is ios 7.1, i changed deploement target to 7.1 and USB cable i am using from apple.

Comment: Whats the error coming on and could you please share the image of current secenario ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149352/discussion-between-minnukaanae-and-salman-ghumsani).