# Account not able to sign in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode8, xcode7

I am new for developing the IOS application. so I have used xcode version 7.3.1 so I am not able to build the IOS 10 version. so xcode 7.3.1 not supported. so I trying to update but it can't able to update because mac has lower version. so I decided to install xip format. then I installed  it, I have tried to build the app in xcode 8.0. then I have deleted the apple id which was already added in xcode 7.3.1. so both version affected it not showing account in xcode. after that I trying to add the account in xcode both version. it getting below given error, please any one help to slove the problem..

[image]

Comment: Please restart your PC and retry again ...

Comment: Yes restarted. but still not working. @ArjunYadav

Comment: may be the problem same as. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466710/how-to-add-the-apple-id-in-xcode-7-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you can login to apple developer:  [Apple Developer Login](https://developer.apple.com/account/)
2. If that is not working, it means it's an issue with either your login credentials, or (more unlikely) there is an issue with Apple's servers and you simply must try later.
3. Try creating a new apple id as a test to see if it's an issue with the apple id, or an issue with your Xcode or computer's setup.

Comment: Yes, It able to login apple Developer and itune , Icloud also.

Comment: 1. can you login into icloud from your computers system preferences / icloud section?
2. Did you try creating a new apple id from the dialog box you posted? As a test to see if it's an issue locally?

Comment: 1. Not able to login in computer its getting verification failed (there was an error connecting to the Apple ID server )

Answer (score 0):

In my case error occurred because of VPN connection.